# How to place a ProgressBar inside of the ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, markup, android-progressbar

I have a ListView that is filled in AsyncTask. At run time, ListView becomes invisible, the ProgressBar is displayed in the center of the horizontal, which disappears after AsyncTask completed, and ListView is displayed again. Now it looks like this:

[image]

But I need to ProgressBar displayed inside of the ListView and is centered both horizontally and vertically:

[image]

Here is my layout markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearHeaderProgress"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">

        <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/HeaderProgress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/listView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use RelativeLayout like this,

```
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/HeaderProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
        </ProgressBar>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Also, in the onCreate() method, set the progress bar as the empty view. `listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.HeaderProgress));` Then, the progress bar will disappear when your list is filled with data.

Comment: @hfann that's something new I learn today, thanks, I will try it.

Comment: @Chitrang , thank you, it works! @hfann , instead of `.setEmptyView()` I use `.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in the `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: @hfann This line: listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.HeaderProgress)); will hide the progress bar after the entries have populated but how we can show up the empty text(No records Found) if the listView is empty .?

Comment: You can have a `TextView` in the layout and set it as the empty view if listview is empty. Make sure you hide the progress bar.

Comment: This solution also helps in case the long list goes beyond the screen and  ProgressBar shifts down